# Ajax Tab container in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I use two user controls in a tab container.user controls inside each tab panel.

I have registration forms  in each user control.if i enter save button of one user control in a tab ,required field validator error coming in second tab panel registration form..how to solve it.
pls help

Answer (score 0):

Add Validation Group property in each control. Then add validation group property in appropriate button.
So when u click on button only than button validation group controls get validated. e.g

```
 <table width="400px">
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 80px;">
                Name :
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtName" ValidationGroup="tab1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" ValidationGroup="tab1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="RequiredFieldValidator"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 80px;">
                Father Name
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtFatherName" ValidationGroup="tab1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" ValidationGroup="tab1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="RequiredFieldValidator"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 80px;">
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:Button ID="btnValidate" runat="server" Text="Validate" ValidationGroup="tab1" 
                    Width="80px" OnClick="btnValidate_Click" />
            </td>
        </tr>           
    </table>
```